# Display condition in a formula in GScript with line wrapping

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to write a formula in GScript with a line break so that the formula becomes clearer? Here's an example:

```
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('visibility = "anyoneCanFind" OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink" OR visibility = "domainCanFind" OR visibility = "domainWithLink"');

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

I would like to display the search criteria in such a way that a new line begins before each "OR".

Is this possible? If yes, could I get a simple example please?

Greetings

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `the formula` is `visibility = "anyoneCanFind" OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink" OR visibility = "domainCanFind" OR visibility = "domainWithLink"`, and you want to achieve the following result.

```
visibility = "anyoneCanFind"
OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink"
OR visibility = "domainCanFind"
OR visibility = "domainWithLink"
```

How about the following modifications?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the template literal is used.

```js
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var q = `
visibility = "anyoneCanFind"
OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink"
OR visibility = "domainCanFind"
OR visibility = "domainWithLink"
`;

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q.trim());
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, each property is added as the text.

```js
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var q = 'visibility = "anyoneCanFind"' +
    'OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink"' +
    'OR visibility = "domainCanFind"' +
    'OR visibility = "domainWithLink"';

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 3:

In this pattern, an array including the values `visibility = "anyoneCanFind"`, `OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink"`, `OR visibility = "domainCanFind"`, and `OR visibility = "domainWithLink"` is used.

```js
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var ar = [
    'visibility = "anyoneCanFind"',
    'OR visibility = "anyoneWithLink"',
    'OR visibility = "domainCanFind"',
    'OR visibility = "domainWithLink"',
  ];
  var q = ar.join("");

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

#### Pattern 4:

In this pattern, an array including the values `"anyoneCanFind", "anyoneWithLink", "domainCanFind", "domainWithLink"` is used.

```js
function myDeleteSharingPublicLinks() {
  var ar = ["anyoneCanFind", "anyoneWithLink", "domainCanFind", "domainWithLink"];
  var q = ar.map(e => `visibility="${e}"`).join(" OR ");

  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(q);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.PRIVATE,DriveApp.Permission.NONE);
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- In your search query, I thought that if you want to skip the files in the trash box, `trashed=false` might be required to be included.

#### References:

- [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hello, mega perfrect - many thanks - for my topic is Pattern 2 ideal.